# Serving Express API via Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm serving a few web applications through firebase. Right now I have 3 custom domains. My domain map looks like this:

```
website - example.com
admin - admin.example.com
api - api.example.com
```

I have the website and admin set up, but I'm struggling to set up my api with the custom domain. I'm not sure how I could hook it up as there's no public directory it just listens on port and routes from there.

Is there a way to do this with just a nodejs (express) rest api and firebase hosting? I've read solutions that incorporate cloud functions, but I'm not planning to implement functions yet.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to host any backend software on Firebase, other than the integration provided by Cloud Functions and Cloud Run.

Comment: ah okay I guess it's just heroku till I further develop the cloud functions